# Can you subscribe to wildcard channels in Faye?

Tags: node.js, faye

I want to a channel with a name `/foo/**/bar` or `/foo/**/buz`. Is this supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wildcards can only be at the end of the path and are denoted with a single asterisk, like `foo/bar/*`

In recent versions of faye, you can only subscribe to wildcard channels, not publish.

Unfortunately, there is no way to get what the value of the wildcard is after a match.